# How to zip and unzip the file with containing same directory structure

Tags: android

I have done some sort of Implementation, when I'm creating zip file everything is fine,zip file is created and it also contains all files without creating directory structure. It means when I unzip the file I have **seen all the files without directory structure**. Please help 
me to sort it out..

Here is the code I have wrriten..

```
public void createZipFolder(String path) 
{   

    File dir = new File(path);
    String list[] = dir.list();
    String name = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/"), path.length());
    String n = path.substring(path.indexOf("/"), path.lastIndexOf("/"));
    Log.d("JWP", "New Path :"+n);

    String newPath;
    if(!dir.canRead() || !dir.canWrite()){
        return;
    }
    int len = list.length;

    if(path.charAt(path.length() - 1) != '/'){
        newPath = n + "/";
    }
    else{
        newPath = n;
    }
    try{
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newPath + name + ".zip"),BUFFER));
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            zip_Folder(new File(path +"/"+ list[i]),zipOut);
        }
        zipOut.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("File Not Found", e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage());
    }       
}



private void zip_Folder(File file, ZipOutputStream zipOut)throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s1 = file.getPath();
    Log.d("JWP", "PATH "+s1);
    byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
    int read;
    if(file.isFile()){
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
        zipOut.putNextEntry(entry);
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        while((read = inputStream.read(data,0,BUFFER)) != -1){
            zipOut.write(data, 0, read);
        }
        zipOut.closeEntry();
        inputStream.close();
    }
    else if(file.isDirectory()){                
            String[] list = file.list();
            int len = list.length;                  
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                zip_Folder(new File(file.getPath()+"/"+ list[i]), zipOut);
        }
    }
```

Here Is the code for Unzip...

```
public void extractZipFiles(String zipFile, String dir){
    Log.d("JWP", "ZIP FILE :"+zipFile+ " DIR :"+dir);
    byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
    String name,path,zipDir;
    ZipEntry entry;
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream;
    if(!(dir.charAt(dir.length() - 1) == '/' )){
        dir += "/";
    }
    if(zipFile.contains("/")){
        path = zipFile;
        name = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.length() - 4);

        zipDir = dir + name + "/";
    }
    else{
        path = dir + zipFile;
        name = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.length() - 4);
        zipDir = dir + name + "/";
    }
    new File(zipDir).mkdir();
    try{
        zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
        while((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null){
            String buildDir = zipDir;
            String dirs[] = entry.getName().split("/");
            if(dirs != null && dirs.length > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < dirs.length - 1; i++){
                    buildDir += dirs[i] + "/";
                    new File(buildDir).mkdir();
                }
            }
            int read = 0;
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(zipDir + entry.getName());
            while((read = zipInputStream.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1){
                out.write(data, 0, read);
            }
            zipInputStream.closeEntry();
            out.close();
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this one ??
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29

Comment: Yes I had, Here is the code of unzip..

Answer (score 0):

You should add folder entries to zip as well.
I.e. create ZipEntry with directory name (and do not forget the trailing slash - it is significant for ZIP archives).
And, add file entries with the full relative path from the directory you are archiving.